# How to copy paste whole HTML pages without wasting abbreviated src linkş?

Tags: html

I have to copy and paste the HTML source of simple webpages (basically landing promotional pages) inside a tool.

I am encountering the following problem: all my img src are being copied in a cut short format, so when I go to the tool the page has lost every image.

As an example,
In the source page I have:

```
 <img src= "https://mycompany.net/content/images/uploads/recent/20190506164011/logo1.png" 
alt="Company logo">
```

And in the copied page it results in:

```
<img src= ".../recent/20190506164011/logo1.png" 
alt="Company logo">
```

Naturally the second (copied) link doesn't work and the (copied) website have only broken images.

Can anybody show me what I am missing and if there's any way to copy the whole src links?

Comment: What are you copying from?

Comment: Why are you copying something that is already exist? This sounds like a problem with the software you're using

Comment: @AlonEitan I have to copy the HTML page to this internal tool we use, which is basically a very simplified HTML editor that people from the Sales&Marketing department utilize to manage campaigns.

Comment: @mlm0b11011 So I think you need to report a bug - Because that tool changes the image url from an absolute one (`https://mycompany.net/content/images/uploads/recent/20190506164011/logo1.png`) to a relative path (`.../recent/20190506164011/logo1.png`), but it places the actual image file in the wrong directory (Or  not saving it at all). It's hard to say what's the problem without knowing the file structure created by that internal tool

Comment: @AlonEitan, yes in my ignorance I thought it could be a shared problem with HTML brute force copypaste, but from what I am gathering I am becoming more and more convinced that it is, as you say, a kind of a bug in our tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what browser you're using but assuming you're using something fairly recent, this should work.

For this you will need to use the browser's console, you can learn about this here: 
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-the-javascript-developer-console

In your browser's console, paste this command and hit enter. It will convert all relative paths '...' to absolute paths.

```
[...document.querySelectorAll('[src]')].forEach(el => el.setAttribute('src', el.getAttribute('src').replace(/^\/{1}/, location.origin + '/')));
```

If you want to get the modified source code of the page, paste the following into your console and hit enter. The outputed text is the page's source code with the changes we made with the previous command.

```
document.documentElement.outerHTML
```

---

Personally, If I were trying to copy an entire site, I would use something like **wget**. Wget is a command line program used to download remote resources like web pages. Its a versatile tool that can be used to easily copy entire web sites.

Here's an example command one might use to copy a whole site:

```
wget --mirror --convert-links --adjust-extension --page-requisites —random-wait —span-hosts -r —level=1 https://example.org
```

If the wget route sounds appealing to you, you can learn more about it here:

https://www.howtogeek.com/281663/how-to-use-wget-the-ultimate-command-line-downloading-tool/

Answer (score 0):

In your editor, replace "..." with the path needed

Comment: My problem is that in the same webpage there can be lots of images and I have to upload many webpages, so it is not feasible to do it manually and I would like to solve the problem at his roots.

Answer (score -1):

within your browser window, Press F12 (if in Windows).  This works for IE and Chrome
This will allow you do see all of the markup language (Elements).  You can then copy+paste.